# Texture not visible on particles

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl, particles

This is the first time I am working with particles (GL_POINTS) I am using kinematic equations and controlling their movement in vertex shader.

I am following an example given in OpenGL 4.0 Cookbook by David Wolff.

I am not able to see the texture which I am loading in the particle.
However, I can see the texture if I put it to some other object, say quad.

[image]

I have increased the size of POINT using glPointSize just so I can see if the texture is really visible.

In the image above you can that I am loading and rendering the same texture for quad, but when I use the same texture for particles, I get different results.
PS: The color which you're seeing for the particles is from the texture itself. If i choose a texture having white color, the same is seen for the particles.

Here is a code from my fragment shader.
I figured if the texture is being displayed correctly for quad, then the issue may not be with the loading of the texture.

```
if(rendPlane == false)
{   
    //vs_fragColor = vec4(.3f,.3f,0.6f,1.00f);
    vs_fragColor = texture(u_particlesTex, gl_PointCoord);
    vs_fragColor.a *= vs_transp;
}   
else
{
    //plane...      
    vs_fragColor = texture(u_particlesTex, vs_texCoord);
}
```

Comment: So it just takes first pixel, hm? `gl_PointCoord` should range from `0` to `1`, thus covering a whole texture easily. Could this be a driver bug? HD Graphics 3000 isn't the most modern GPU out there, if you could test on some other reference platform, it might help in confirming that.

Comment: I did actually, I have switchable graphics **on Nvidia GT 555m the same result was observed**.
I did not bother to change the GPU for the sake of screenshot.

Comment: I believe this post has some info on this behaviour: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11113/gl-pointcoord-always-zero

Comment: I already have latest drivers installed.
Still stuck with this. :(

Comment: @2am Could you post your results if you just output `gl_PointCoord`   to vs_fragColor? If it will be one color, then the `gl_PointCoord` variable is not correctly set.

Comment: Yes, it is one color, but i had to do something like this... because vs_fragColor is vec4 and gl_PointCoord is vec2 `vs_fragColor = vec4(gl_PointCoord, 1.0f, 1.0f);` 

I hope this is what you were trying to say..

Ok, so now, gl_PointCoord is not set correctly, I wonder how we set that variable manually, as ths is set by OpenGL if we use GL_POINTS [also I am not so good with texture coordinates :) ]

Anyway, thanks. :)